# Style divider link between images in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I style a divider link between images, using **CSS**?

**Desired output**:

[image: Image 1]

**Actual result**:

[image: Image 1]

The result is not the same as the in the picture, and the 2 lines overlap.

Here's the **HTML**/**CSS**, and an example:

```css
.divider {
  padding: 0px 180px;
}

.style-seven {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-left: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 85%;
}

.style-seven-2 {
  border-top: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-right: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div class="style-seven"></div>
  <div class="style-seven-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with just two elements and their pseudo-elements. Adjust outer element height and horizontal margin to suit size requirements.

```css
.divider {
  height: 100px; /* total divider height - could also be fluid */
  margin: 0 50px; /* spacing from parent element at sides */
  position: relative;
}

.divider::before,
.divider::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(50% - .5px);  /* allow for half the border width */
  width: calc(50% - .5px);  /* allow for half the border width */
}

.divider::before {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-left: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.divider::after {
  border-top: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-right: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.divider-ends::before,
.divider-ends::after {
  content: '•';
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}

.divider-ends::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* shift half of character width */
}

.divider-ends::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%); /* shift half of character width */
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div class="divider-ends">
</div>
```